# Rename legend on export in highchart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, export

I know highcharts makes it possible to update a legend by using the following function:

```
chart.legend.allItems[0].update({name:'aaa'});
```

Also the possibility to hide or show the legends on export are working.

```
 exporting:{
   chartOptions:{
            legend:{
                enabled:true
            }
        }
  }
```

But now, I like to rename a specific legend during export. Is there any way to bind the update code to the export-function in Highcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update series in the `chart.events.load` event, for example:

```
exporting: {
  chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      events: {
        load: function (e) { 
           this.series[0].update({ name: "New name." });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```